# Erlang error: no function clause matching io:request

Tags: erlang

I'm an experienced programmer new to Erlang and I'm stuck on the following:

```
myread() ->
    {_, MyData } = file:read_file( "hands.txt" ),
    io:format( "hands-out.txt", "~w", MyData ).
```

yields, when myread() is invoked from the shell:

```
** exception error: no function clause matching io:request("hands-out.txt",
          {format,"~w", <<"3h 5h 7h 8h 3h 5h 7h 8h q"...>>}) 
      (io.erl, line 556)  in function  io:o_request/3 (io.erl, line 63)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Two things:

`"hands-out.txt", "~w"` needs to be one string: `"hands-out.txt: ~w"`

and the data that's replacing the `~w` needs to be a list. So:

`io:format( "hands-out.txt: ~w", [MyData] ).`

See http://erlang.org/doc/man/io.html#format-2

Also, you should pattern match on the status value in the return from `file:read_file/1`. In your version, an error, which would be returned as `{error, Reason}` would match here, since you're using `_`, and you'd print the error reason rather than the file, which might be confusing.

So either make it `{ok, MyData } = file:read_file( "hands.txt" )` if you want to crash on read error, or something like the following if you want to handle that case:

```
myread() ->
  case file:read_file( "hands.txt" ) of
    {ok, MyData } ->
      io:format( "hands-out.txt: ~w", [MyData] );
    {error, Error} ->
      io:format("Error: ~w~n", [Error])
  end.
```